# how do display oracle table using php

Tags: php, android, oracle, blob

i have oracle table named Ben_audio where i saved multiple data like ID, ATTENDANT, CURRENT DATE, and REC_AUDIO (its a base 64 String not actual file), now what i want you to help me to display all the data in JSON format in PHP. i am newbie to PHP please help me out of this problem, please see the attached picture let me know the response, thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tys7Y.png)

i tried this code.

```
$query = "SELECT ID, ATTENDENT, CUR_DATE from BEN_AUDIO where VISITNO  = '$VISITNO'";
$statment = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($statment);

 $json_array = array();
    
while ($row=oci_fetch_array($statment))
{
    $json_array[] = $row;
    //echo "<br>", $row['VISITNO'], " - ", $row['URN'], " - ", $row['ADMDATETIME'], "-", $row['DISCHGDT'],"<br>";
    
}
    
      echo json_encode($json_array);
     // json_encode($json_array);

   oci_free_statement($statment);
   oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: You seem to have the various parts you need to do this, is something not working as you would expect?

Comment: the query mention above is not working, when i try to display all the fields excluding REC_AUDIO field which is a blob field is working, but when i want to display all fields including REC_AUDIO it show nothing.

Comment: if REC_AUDIO is a BLOB, what exactly do you want to show ? it is a binary object, and for the description it looks like an audio file somehow.

Comment: i have inserted base64 string in blob field now i want that base 64 string to be display in php